# Drop Down menu in java?

Tags: java, swing, drop-down-menu

I created drop down list using java. But i am not aware of creating drop down menu like as Sliding menu. Is it possible create the drop down menu using java?

Comment: You should precise the used toolkit (Swing ? SWT ? Web application ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean a File menu at the top of the screen?

If so you should look at the class `JMenuBar`.

Here is a [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) on how to create them in Swing.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone looks for the same thing in AWT: `java.awt.Choice` = Drop-down-menu